# Blazor AuthorizeView: How to use Custom Authorization Filter

Tags: c#, razor, authorization, blazor, blazor-boilerplate

I'm working with this code from the Blazor Boilerplate: ([BlazorBoilerPlate GitHub](https://github.com/enkodellc/blazorboilerplate))

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components
@inject NavigationManager navigationManager
@inject AuthenticationStateProvider authStateProvider

<AuthorizeView Context="AuthorizeContext">
<Authorized>
    <MatTooltip Tooltip="Logout">
        <MatIconButton Icon="exit_to_app" RefBack="@context" OnClick="LogoutClick"></MatIconButton>
    </MatTooltip>
</Authorized>
<NotAuthorized>
    <MatTooltip Tooltip="Login">
        <MatIconButton Icon="account_box" RefBack="@context" Link="/account/login"></MatIconButton>
    </MatTooltip>
</NotAuthorized>
```

```
@code {
     async Task LogoutClick()
     {
          await ((IdentityAuthenticationStateProvider)authStateProvider).Logout();
     navigationManager.NavigateTo("/account/login");
     }
}
```

Where does the "AuthorizeContext" come from? Depency Injection?  How can I use my own custom Authorization Filter here.

Just looking for any guesses or info anyone knows regarding this specific argument.

Here is my custom AuthorizationFilter, I don't know how to use it within the blazor razor file.

```
namespace BlazorBoilerplate.Shared.AuthorizationDefinitions
```

{
    public class OfficeAuthorize : IAuthorizationFilter
    {
        private readonly string _scenario;

```
    public OfficeAuthorize(string scenario)
    {
        _scenario = scenario;
    }

    public void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationFilterContext context)
    {
        //context.HttpContext.Request.Query
        //custom validation rule
        if (_scenario == "OfficeAssignment")
        {
            context.Result = new ForbidResult();
        }
    }
}

public class OfficeAuthorizeAttribute : TypeFilterAttribute
{
    public OfficeAuthorizeAttribute(int input) : base(typeof(OfficeAuthorize))
    {
        Arguments = new object[] { input };
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Hover Context in VS, you'll see: "specifies the parameter name for all child content expressions". It's not injected into the AuthorizeView component, it's the name you want to give that components context that is available to it's children. Only need to give it a name if it's colliding with another context (maybe an EditForm), default name is "context".

Comment: I don't know about exactly what you're trying to do, but AuthorizeView can take a comma-delimited list of roles in the Roles parameter, or a policy name in the Policy parameter.

Answer (score 4):

You can wrap the `AuthorizeView` component with a custom one. This is loosely based on the framework code.

```cs
public class CustomAuthorizationView : AuthorizeView
{
    private AuthenticationState currentAuthenticationState;
    private bool isAuthorized;

    [Inject]
    private AuthenticationStateProvider AuthenticationStateProvider { get; set; }

    [CascadingParameter] 
    private Task<AuthenticationState> AuthenticationStateTask { get; set; }

    protected override void BuildRenderTree(RenderTreeBuilder builder)
    {
        if (currentAuthenticationState == null)
        {
            builder.AddContent(0, Authorizing);
        }
        else if (isAuthorized)
        {
            var authorizedContent = Authorized ?? ChildContent;
            builder.AddContent(1, authorizedContent?.Invoke(currentAuthenticationState));
        }
        else
        {
            builder.AddContent(2, NotAuthorized?.Invoke(currentAuthenticationState));
        }
    }

    protected override async Task OnParametersSetAsync()
    {           
        var user = (await authenticationStateProvider.GetAuthenticationStateAsync()).User;
        currentAuthenticationState = await AuthenticationStateTask;
        isAuthorized = //authorization logic
    }
}
```